# Moving the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to move the page from top to bottom, just like it happens in the best site of the world( [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)), when we change the type of sorting of our questions, it moves the page.

How can I get such an effect?
I even don't know how to search for information about it, because don't know the *keywords*, so I decided to ask here :/

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? You said SO does this, can you give an example of what you're talking about? That should make it much clearer.

Comment: @SLaks, dejavu: Go to your profiles and click on any button to the right of your "Questions" or "Answers" (the buttons are: `recent`, `views`, `newest`, `votes`) to see the effect in action.

Comment: I think he meant the jquery effect that is triggered when you refresh new post in a discussion.... when the page scroll down inserting new posts between old and your post....

Comment: I suspect he means auto-scrolling effect but not sure of course

Comment: Do you mean that the displayed "Question" shows the newest or last edited at the top, then "moves" down the page as items more recent are posted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you mean scrolling the page automatically? If so, have a look at:

[jQuery ScrollTo plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

See this [demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) to confirm if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Exactly;) i did't know, that there is such plugin there:) Thanks much
p.s (i haven't learned to clearly ask questions:( yet)

Answer (score 4):

keywords: "scroll page to position using javascript" in particular, you want the [window.scrollTo()](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/ecmascript/quickref/win_scrollto.html) method

```
window.scrollTo(x,y);
```

that exists in native JavaScript, or a jQuery method that wraps this (e.g. jQuery [ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin).